# Taking space separated input in loop with python

Tags: python

I'm still learning python, so this may seem silly.
This is the C++ code i want the python equivalent of:

```
int t;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>t;
    ans = do_something(t);
}
cout<<ans;
```

I can do this by making **t** a list and then using each element as do_something's parameter, but i want a solution similar to the C++ code.
Also input **t** is taken space separated.
Eg

```
1 2 3 4 5
ans
```

`

Comment: for loop, raw_input and print show do the job, You should learn python first, - https://docs.python.org/2.7/contents.html

Comment: what is the do_somthing() doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input_from_user = raw_input() #which is a string '1 2 3 4 5'
numbers = input_from_user.split()
>>> ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
numbers = map(int, numbers) #To convert the string elements to integers.
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in numbers:
    ans = do_something(i)
print ans
```

Or you can do this thing in single line as :

```
for i in map(int,raw_input().split()):
    ans = do_something(i)
print ans
```